# Error while building ndk library

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a .so file from the netguard native library in jni folder but I get this error "collect2 ld returned 1 exit status" after I execute "ndk-build". please I would like someone help create a .so file.

Project path: https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard

My Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
APP_PROJECT_PATH := /home/mishael/AndroidStudioProjects/NetGuard/app/src/main/jni/netguard/      
APP_PLATFORM=android-14 
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips 
LOCAL_MODULE := netguard
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := netguard.c 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Error Message

```
ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk [armeabi] Compile thumb :    
netguard <= netguard.c In file included from ./netguard.c:20:0:   
./netguard.h:203:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty 
declaration [enabled by default] } __packed; ^ ./netguard.h:210:1: 
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by 
default] } __packed; ^ ./netguard.h:262:1: warning: useless storage class 
specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default] } __packed; ^ 
./netguard.h:284:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty 
declaration [enabled by default] } __packed; ^ ./netguard.h:289:1:   
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by 
default] } __packed; ^ ./netguard.c: In function 
'Java_eu_faircode_netguard_SinkholeService_jni_get_stats': 
./netguard.c:216:5: warning: passing argument 4 of 
'(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements' makes integer from pointer without a 
cast [enabled by default] (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, jarray,    
jcount, NULL); ^ ./netguard.c:216:5: note: expected 'jint' but argument   
is of type 'void *' [armeabi] SharedLibrary : libnetguard.so    
./netguard.c:84: error: undefined reference to 'log_android' 
./netguard.c:88: error: undefined reference to 'log_android' 
./netguard.c:104: error: undefined reference to 'init_icmp' 
./netguard.c:105: error: undefined reference to 'init_udp' 
./netguard.c:106: error: undefined reference to 'init_tcp' 
./netguard.c:111: error: undefined reference to 'log_android' 
./netguard.c:112: error: undefined reference to 'pcap_file' 
./netguard.c:120: error: undefined reference to 'log_android' 
./netguard.c:151: error: undefined reference to 'max_tun_msg' 
./netguard.c:151: error: undefined reference to 'handle_events' 
./netguard.c:172: error: undefined reference to 'clear_icmp' 
./netguard.c:173: error: undefined reference to 'clear_udp' 
./netguard.c:174: error: undefined reference to 'clear_tcp' 
./netguard.c:194: error: undefined reference to 'get_icmp_sessions' 
./netguard.c:195: error: undefined reference to 'get_udp_sessions' 
./netguard.c:196: error: undefined reference to 'get_tcp_sessions' 
./netguard.c:265: error: undefined reference to 'write_pcap_hdr' 
./netguard.c:276: error: undefined reference to 'pcap_record_size' 
./netguard.c:276: error: undefined reference to 'pcap_file_size'   
./netguard.c:276: error: undefined reference to 'pcap_file' 
./netguard.c:283: error: undefined reference to 'clear_icmp' 
./netguard.c:284: error: undefined reference to 'clear_udp' 
./netguard.c:285: error: undefined reference to 'clear_tcp' collect2: 
error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [/home/mishael
/AndroidStudioProjects/NetGuard/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi
/libnetguard.so] Error 1
```

Comment: You forgot to link in some library

Comment: Try to change this `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog` to `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog`

Comment: @LPs i still get the  collect2: 
error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [/home/mishael
/AndroidStudioProjects/NetGuard/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi
/libnetguard.so] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Building the NetGuard native code is integrated in the NetGuard Android Studio project, so I guess you are making this more difficult than it is.